# R shiny: loading icon works in browser, but not when run in Rstudio

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

using the code chunk below I've added a loading icon to my Shiny app. However, it only shows the icon when I've opened the app within my web browser and not when I'm just running it within Rstudio. Is there a way I can change this so it appears in both interfaces?

Thanks!

```
tagList(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css",href="style.css"),
      tags$script(type="text/javascript", src = "busy.js")
    )
  ),
div(class = "busy",
      p("Calculation in progress.."),
      img(src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif")
  ),
plotOutput("distPlot"),
```

Answer (score 0):

It will probably work if you download the image and access it from a local path. I think what you're seeing is a bug I reported in shiny a while ago: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1148

Comment: So I moved the image to a local path and it still doesn't work. There's also not even a blank jpg image like if I put an incorrect link; within Rstudio's it's as if the tagList and div commands aren't even there